# Icon image not appearing in smart banner in chrome

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome

An icon image is not appearing in Chrome. It's appearing in Safari, however. My JSP code is:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=499106876">
<meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.rexel.iphone02.RexelUSA">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.smartbanner.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/nedco_favicon.png"/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

con(function() { con.smartbanner() } )

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have icon set only for apple... You need set it for android too.

Add this:

```
<link rel="android-touch-icon" href="/nedco_favicon.png"/>
```

Comment: This seems to fail some HTML validators. What's your source of information for android-touch-icon?

Answer (score 0):

use this tag for android for chrome

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="196x196" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Source is [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons)